# How could I make a list appear 'clickable/touchable?'

Tags: mobile, lists, touch-screen, indicator

So I've got a nice ol' list that, when you tap on the sections, brings up more information. However, just looking at the list doesn't make it very clear you can expand them. But I'm not sure how I can show they are touchable--I'm coming up blank.

(Also apologies for the quickie PS mock-ups and guides.)

The blue on the second image indicates which has been clicked/tapped.

[image: Standard list view]

[image: List view with a section selected after being tapped]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a good article that explains the problem and give some tips on how to solve it.

[**Making Hit Areas Sufficiently Distinct**](http://baymard.com/blog/mobile-product-list-hit-areas)

[image]

Also there is a good read by nngroup

[**Beyond Blue Links: Making Clickable Elements Recognizable**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/clickable-elements/)

About this problem in the desktop platform, there you can find some more tips on how to approach this issue.

TL;DR
Use some kind of visual aid to make your users to understand that they can click each item to get more information about it.

I would add a small icon and a label "more info" at the bottom right corner of each list item that will be clickable, but also I would make the whole list item clickable.

Comment: Helpful resources, and I would say the first screenshot in the first link would be an excellent solution in this case.

Comment: These are awesome resources, thanks so much! I feel silly for not thinking of some of these--sometimes you just need to see it right in front of your face and then it sinks in. ;)

Comment: You are welcome @user82223. would appreciate an upvote (or mark as correct :) )